# How to deal with wrong range position?

Tags: salary, negotiation, united-kingdom

This is the first time that I have this problem and I don't know anybody who hear or had to deal with.

I joined my current company as Data Engineer a bit more than 1 year ago from an internal recruiter which left the company a few months ago.
In the negotiation I asked for one amount of salary but, as I didn't have experience in their environment, the offer was a bit lower and the range junior.

So, after this year, I asked to get promotion to regular as I don't do junior work. The surprise was when my manager (he started 3 months ago, the one which I started with left) told me that I was already regular engineer.

After some investigation apparently I've been regular engineer from the beginning due, probably, an error from HR.

Now I asked for a pay raise as I am regular and not junior and the money that I didn't get pay during this year (difference junior and regular).

My questions are:

- I don't have any clear number for what Regular so how is the best way to negotiate this?
- Negotiate with one employee for one range/role and change it without notification legal? (I'm UK based)
- Which is the best option to proceed?

Comment: what does "change it without notification legal" mean ?

Comment: You seem to be asking whether you are entitled to a _back-dated_ pay rise -- am I right? If so, the answer is a resounding NO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Now I asked for a pay raise as I am regular and not junior and the money that I didn't get pay during this year (difference junior and regular).

You may be able to get a pay rise going forward, if you argue your position enough (and here's the clincher, if you're also prepared to leave if you don't get said raise.)

However, unless you've signed a contract saying you're on one pay scale but have been paid at a lower rate for the duration of your employment, you can almost certainly forget about any possibility of claiming a raise historically!

Answer (score 3):

> I don't have any clear number for what Regular so how is the best way to negotiate this?

Do some research into comparable salaries. Think about what's fair. Come up with a number you're willing to accept.

> Negotiate with one employee for one range/role and change it without notification legal? (I'm UK based)

We cannot answer legal questions. You'd have to talk to a lawyer, but it doesn't sound like any damage has been done (you were given a higher position than you thought you were getting after all).

> Which is the best option to proceed?

You seem to already know the answer: negotiate fair pay for the quality of work you're providing.

Comment: I get a higher position but they negotiate with me based in a lower one so my salary is lower so basically I'm underpaid because they made that mistake (I really hope is not a lie).
Also I expected a pay raise when I get the promotion, which I don't have, at least for now

Answer (score 2):

Many companies are receptive to "you hired me to do junior work, paid me to do junior work, and had me doing upper-level work, can i get a raise?" It's pretty much the basis of receiving a raise or promotion.

There's upside as well: you can list upper-level experience on your resume instead of junior, and go find another job for a potentially substantial increase in wages.

The downside is that even if they own up to their mistake, your raise may be inherently capped due to company policy at 3, 5 or 10%. You might exceed these figures by simply applying at a different company. The fact you're already working there hurts the ceiling on anything you attempt to negotiate.

Answer (score 0):

You have made your bed I am afraid

Some options might include:

1 Ask other "regulars" what they make

2 Ask HR for the pay scales

3 Ask for the industry rate for the Job

4 Interview outside to get a feel what the rate is

I Suspect that you come from a culture where Junior /Senior etc count for a lot more that's not the way it works in the UK saying " I don't junior work " wont do you any favours with HR or your peers.

Comment: It's not the junior/regular thing important, its more the fact of offer me one position and then change it without notice

Comment: What did your offer letter say when compared to your contract?

Comment: The offer said Junior Data Engineer and contract Data Engineer, it didn't have any range so they say that's regular